# Changing battery of capacitor

Tags: electricity, capacitance

Say a capacitor is charged to its fullest capacity by a battery of $5\rm\ V$ and capacitance is $2\rm\ C/V$. The battery is now replaced by a $K\rm\ Volts$ voltage one. How will the current flow? Note the above values are made up and not from any sum so calculations might not  be uniform. I basically want to know whether charging will continue or will it be discharged  if $K < 5\rm\ V$ and  $K > 5\rm\ V$.

Comment: What do you mean by 2C/V?

Comment: unit of capacitance as coulumbs / volt .

Comment: Why not just say 2 F?

Answer (score 1):

In either case the final voltage over the capacitor will be $K$ and the final charge will be $KC$ where C is the capacitance. For $K>5V$ the charge will increase and for $K <5V$ the charge will decrease.

Depending on the exact details on how the battery is constructed the case $K < 5V$ can potentially damage the battery or voltage source. It would be advisable to put a current limiting resistor in series with the capacitor.